# are there "public" ethereum nodes? or any recommendations on hosting solutions?

Tags: solidity, ether, json-rpc, testrpc, nodes

I've always ran apps on Heroku. Just developed a smart contract and I need to check the blockchain from the app. Are there public nodes I can connect to to get the info I need to show on my app?

If not, have you set up an ethereum node on a hosting service you can recommend?

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Infura is the most prominent public Ethereum nodes. They run mainnet and many of the testnets. They also run IPFS servers. http://infura.io.

Comment: I just learned about infura a few days ago and came here to update my answer.  Beat me to it!  +1

Answer (score 4):

In addition to [Infura](https://infura.io/), [Alchemy](https://alchemyapi.io/) and [QuickNode](https://quiknode.io/) offer Ethereum Nodes as a service. These services offer full JSON-RPC APIs, whereas Etherscan supports a limited number of the JSON-RPC APIs.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't seen any public RPC nodes(yet).  However, you may want to ask yourself whether or not you can actually trust such a node.  In theory, that node could feed you whatever data it wanted.

That said, there may be better options but you don't really say what you're goal is there.  [etherscan has an API](https://etherscan.io/apis) that could potentially be useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good list of up-to-date nodes; some with APIs:
https://ethereumnodes.com/