# What RPC APIs are safe to expose?

Tags: web3js, rpc

What RPC APIs are safe to expose (make public, so accessible by anyone), and what are the unsafe ones, and why?

I've read:

- [are there "public" ethereum nodes? or any recommendations on hosting solutions?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/16831/are-there-public-ethereum-nodes-or-any-recommendations-on-hosting-solutions)