# Which JSONRPC APIs are required by MetaMask?

Tags: parity, json-rpc, security, metamask

This question is related to [What RPC APIs are safe to expose?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/27829/what-rpc-apis-are-safe-to-expose)

I want to run a Parity node not to have a wallet but only to have my own personal JSON RPC node for MetaMask. Parity will not be running on the same host as the browser with MetaMask.

According to https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/JSONRPC, by default the following JSON RPC APIs are enabled:

```
web3,eth,pubsub,net,parity,parity_pubsub,traces,rpc,secretstore.
```

Which ones are absolutely required to use MetaMask and which ones can be disabled?

Answer (score 2):

As long as you don't run with an account unlocked, the node is safe to expose, and only performs fairly public operations. For a precise list of methods used by MetaMask, refer to this:

https://github.com/MetaMask/provider-engine#data-source--fallback-to-rpc-